# ADB devices - Get all IPs matching the device state

Tags: android, bash, shell, parsing, adb

When I issue command:

```
adb devices
```

I have result like this:

```
List of devices attached
192.168.1.200:5555      offline
192.168.1.201:5555      device
192.168.1.202:5555      unauthorized
192.168.1.203:5555      device
```

I have this bash script, but is failing cos it's working only on connected devices:

```
#!/bin/bash
#init
a=$(adb devices | cut -f1 | cut -f1 -d\ );
echo $a;
for x in $a;
do 
    if [ "$x" == "List" ]; 
        then continue; 
    fi;
    echo $x
    adb connect $x
done
```

How to only get IPs from "device" in list and skip IPs from other values in list?

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 0):

Use the "grep" command to filter by the name and no need for additional "cut"

```
a=$(adb devices | grep "device" | cut -f1 -d\);
```

Comment: Notice that grep matches `device` anywhere on the line, so it matches the title too. Use `awk` as others suggest or at least `grep 'device$'` to anchor at the end onf the line.

Answer (score 0):

`a=$(adb devices | sed "1 d" | grep "device" | cut -f1 -d\ );`

Added two more filter:

`sed "1 d"` - omit first line, print everything else

`grep "device"` - print only lines that contain "device"

You can remove the if statement, as it is handled by the `sed` filter.